# why am I receiving the run time error 3346

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have a problem with my vba access code im getting the

> run time error 3346: Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO UndoLapse_Log (Policy_ID, Client_Name, User) VALUES (" & Forms!CosmeticSubform!.PolicyIDResult & ", '" & Replace(DLookup("Client_Name", "Clients", "ClientID =" & Forms!CosmeticSubform!.ClientIDResult), "'", "''") & "'), '" & User & "'")
```

please help thanks.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted this only to help pinpoint the issue and so it makes since from a visual perspective. You have an out of place parenthesis and its confusing the compiler because it thinks your VALUES are less than the amount of columns you stated. The parenthesis in question actually needs to be moved down.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL 
    ("INSERT INTO UndoLapse_Log 
        (
            Policy_ID
            , Client_Name
            , User
        ) 
    VALUES 
        (
            " & Forms!CosmeticSubform!.PolicyIDResult & "
            , '" & Replace
                        (
                            DLookup
                                (
                                    "Client_Name", "Clients", "ClientID =" & Forms!CosmeticSubform!.ClientIDResult
                                )
                            , "'", "''"
                        ) & "')      '''THIS IS AN OUT OF PLACE PARENTHESIS
            , '" & User & "'"  ''' THIS IS WHERE IT OUGHT TO BE
    )
```